# How might one render an individual sub-Block of a StreamField?

Tags: wagtail

I've got a conundrum that I'm hoping a Wagtail internals expert can help me solve. What I'm ultimately trying to do is render a complex, nested StreamField-based Page as plaintext/HTML that can be used for search indexing and for displaying as a snippet on a search results page.

The issue is that some of the blocks on the page should *not* be included in the search index, as they contain metadata about other, mostly unrelated pages. So I don't want searches for Page A to bring up results that merely reference Page A.

The solution I've come up with is to manually walk the block tree and only render certain kinds of blocks within the StreamField. But while this was relatively easy for `RichTextBlock`, since I can just snag the 'value' string out of the block dict, it's not simple at all for any of our custom blocks.

I would like to render the HTML for an individual block, but I'm really not sure how to do so, if such a thing is even possible. After digging deep into the render pipeline for StreamField, my best lead is that I might be able to manually build a `BoundBlock` with the appropriate data, and then call `render()` on that. But I'm not really sure how to take a raw block dict and turn it into a `StreamValue` for the `BoundBlock` to be built from. If that's even the right idea...

I'm also working on a reverse solution, in case I'm just barking up the wrong tree, here. I figured that I might be able to pass a particular context variable into `StreamField.render_as_block(context)` in the function that generates the search index, which I can program the individual blocks to look for, and then not to render themselves at all if they see it. I will update this question if I manage to get that working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understand correctly, but you can iterate over the blocks of a StreamField. Some example:

**Block definition:**

```
class MyCustomImageBlock(StructBlock):
  image = ImageChooserBlock()
  caption = CharBlock()

  class Meta:
    template = '/blocks/image-with-caption.html'
    icon = 'image'

class MyCarouselBlock(ListBlock):

  class Meta:
    template = '/blocks/custom-list.html'
    icon = 'media'
```

ImageWithCaptionblock

**Custom StreamBlock definition:**

```
class MyCustomStreamBlock(StreamBlock):

  some_image = MyCustomImageBlock()
  image_carousel = MyCarouselBlock(child_block=MyCustomImageBlock)
```

**Page definition:**

```python
class MyPage(Page):

  content = StreamField(MyCustomStreamBlock())
```

**Template**

Now you can simply render over the blocks of the StreamField, and use the include_block to render the individual blocks. And you can pass variables as well.

```
{% for block in page.content %}
  {% include_block block with current_page=page %} # in case you want to render only something when on a certain page
{% endfor %}
```

Some technique I use frequently is this:
Create a custom StreamBlock which consists of only 1 type of custom block. Then cycle over some variables to render the data the content editor has defined with different styling for each block:

```
{% for block in page.content %}
  <!--
  {% cycle 'right' 'left' as position %}
  {% cycle 'primary' 'secondary' 'white' as color %}
  -->
  {% include_block block with pos=position color=color %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ahhh, you know what? I hadn't thought to do it that way, because I've been thinking about it from a different angle. But I think that'd totally work, with a few tweaks to make it fit my needs. Thanks!